# Ansible : Pass task dict as variable

Tags: ansible

I am trying to achieve this :

roles/stuff/defaults/main.yml :

```
cool_stuff: msg="yo man"
```

roles/stuff/tasks/main.yml :

```
- debug: "{{ cool_stuff }}"
```

This is the result I get :

```
TASK [dummy : debug] ***********************************************************
task path: .../tasks/main.yml:3
ok: [sandbox-a] => {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}
```

How to get this instead ? :

```
TASK [dummy : debug] ***********************************************************
task path: .../tasks/main.yml:3
ok: [sandbox-a] => {
    "msg": "yo man"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Where does the "Hello world!" come from?

Comment: It's the default debug msg value : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html

Answer (score 1):

The correct [syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html#debug-print-statements-during-execution) is either

```
- debug:
    msg:  "{{ cool_stuff }}"
```

or

```
- debug:
    var:  cool_stuff
```

This is the generic message `"msg": "Hello world!"` printed when *msg* and *var* are omitted.